# Array of custom objects - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I have this piece of code, I have a problem trying to create an array of users.

if I use "**var userArray: [Users] = FakeData**" gives me the following error "Can not convert value of type 'User_TableViewController -> () -> [Users]' to specified type '[Users]'"

if I use "**var userArray: [Users] = FakeData()**" gives me the following error "Missing argument for parameter # 1 in call"

if I use "**var userArray: [Users] = [FakeDate]**" I get the following error "Use of unresolved identifier 'FakeDate'"

What is the problem? I ran out of ideas xD

```
class User_TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var userArray:[Users] = FakeData()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return userArray.count
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let Cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("userCell") as! UserCell_TableViewCell
        Cell.userImage.image = userArray[indexPath.row].getImage()
        Cell.userDescription?.text = userArray[indexPath.row].getFirstName()

        return Cell
    }

    func FakeData() -> [Users]{

        let Person1 = Users(firstName: "Usuario 1", lastName: "Apellido 1", email: "mail1@hotmail.com", password: "1234567", age: "18", gender: "Male", image: UIImage(named: "Apple48x48")!)
        let Person2 = Users(firstName: "Usuario 2", lastName: "Apellido 2", email: "mail2@hotmail.com", password: "1234567", age: "18", gender: "Male", image: UIImage(named: "Apple48x48")!)
        let Person3 = Users(firstName: "Usuario 3", lastName: "Apellido 3", email: "mail3@hotmail.com", password: "1234567", age: "18", gender: "Male", image: UIImage(named: "Apple48x48")!)

        return [Person1, Person2, Person3]

    }

}
```

Comment: what is FakeData? The usual syntax is supposed to be `var userArray = [Users]()`, the annotation is not needed.

Comment: FakeData is a method in OPs class, it's in the question.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I thought it was a class (weird spelling)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be initializing the array inside a method, like `viewDidLoad` or `init`. For the property declaration either set

```
var userArray:[Users]!
```

or

```
var userArray:[Users] = []
```

Then inside (for example) `viewDidLoad`:

```
userArray = FakeData()
```

(Also convention is to name methods starting with lowercase letters, so `fakeData()`, in one of your attempts you wrote FakeDate instead of FakeData, and also variable names should also start with a lowercase letter i.e. cell not Cell)

Comment: Thx for all the coments!